# Causes for really long page Request times?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, publishing-page, reporting-services

We have a sharepoint portal running SSRS reports for our customers.

The reports themselves dont take that long to render, however the page requests take over 10-15 seconds which is simply unacceptable from a customers perspective.

How can I overcome this? Is there anything in particualr I can do to improve performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running this using SharePoint integrated mode that would be one possible explanation. What versions of SharePoint and SSRS are you running? We switched everything to Native Mode and it runs much quicker. Microsoft has tried addressing this with Sql Server 2012 and a new report viewer control, but our experience was native mode was still quicker. You will lose some of the convenience of the integration, like managing security in one place, but for us the performance concerns outweighed the convenience.

There are other examples but this is a good one of someone else who had the same problem:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/4ed01ff4-139a-4eb3-9e2e-df12a9c316ff

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the post! We are running SQL2008 R2 with SP1 and the Reporting Services Add-in (SP1 version ending in .2500). 

When you say your performance got better could you give me a number/precentage in performance increase please.

Comment: I don't have any official numbers since this is not an in-house application but a product we sell ( so every client environment is different ). However, I would say in my local dev box running two ssrs reports simultaneously on the same page went from 20-30 seconds to 5-10 seconds on average. There are obviously a lot of factors like the amount of data, the report type, etc. However, if the report runs fine in BIDS, it will probably run just as well in Native Mode.

Comment: 2 things here:
1. The sharepoint page request itself takes voer 20s (due to the JIT lag caused on every first hit)

2. The reports render slow the first time around till things get cached and then it all speeds up (when I say speeds up, I mean 2-5 seconds on any report in integrated mode)

Im really looking to deal with the "Warm up" aspect of the application. Everything else seems to be looking decent enough. 

Thanks for all the input! Let me know if you do come across any related info.

Comment: We created a timer job that pings the report pages to keep them alive. I've seen some similar timer jobs online that you can probably search for. If you have trouble finding them let me know.

Comment: I found a warm up script which seems to achieve something similar: http://blog.karstein-consulting.com/2011/08/03/sharepoint-warm-up-now-with-timeout/

but did not see any difference in first request performance

Could you run me through the timer job setup that you'll have in place please?

Comment: We didn't use PowerShell, rather we used C#. Ours was based on this concept by Andrew Connell: http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2010/03/27/introducing-the-sharepoint-site-collection-keep-alive-job.aspx. We added the ability to load specific pages via a URL property, however. Basically it uses a HttpWebRequest object to get a response, like so:        response = ( HttpWebResponse )request.GetResponse( );